# combine two forms into one

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, forms

just searched in vain, do you pls advise how combining these two simple forms in one like BOX+ SELECT +BUTTON 
Hurdle to me is combining the two different actions="..asp" into one script for ASP.

```
<form action="listItems.asp">
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="strSearch" placeholder="Products"> 
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>


<form action="listlocations.asp" >
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Locations">
        <input type="hidden" name="i" value="61b42810d83e6feaca5bb3ca7b3e76cd" scrolling="no">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
```

Comment: Combining the form in UI side can be done fairly easily, Point is how are you planning to handle the posted data in your server side. Do you have a plan for it?

Comment: Thanks Reddy, sure thing, both forms work well independently, for the first one the page listItems.asp GETs data for       mySQL="SELECT categoryDesc, details, imageCategory FROM categories WHERE idCategory="&pIdCategory
 call getFromDatabase (mySql, rsTemp, "listItems.asp")                   while the second one is a BatchGeo map, so it needs the i+q variables (<input>, if you'd have an idea how to merge the two forms with only one GO button, a SELECT, and TXT box would be awesome       BOTH ones ask a TEXT to input, 1st form uses for products, 2nd one for Locations

Comment: Ok what should be the `action` atrribute` value after merge?

Comment: Hey, faily easy but it's not, what you mean for easy, please

Comment: I only thought something like the image below here (EXAMPLE): box, select, button.

Comment: On the UI side you can use Jquery and combine two forms into one form tag.

Answer (score 0):

[2 combined forms IMG EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AU3W.png)

first one returns a list of products example bungees
....listItems.asp?strSearch=bungee

the second one
needs  i and q variables as coordinates for BatchGeo map.

I saw a script like as follows, but I have 2 actions="page" and each a different input name="..."

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dosearch() {
var sf=document.searchform;
var submitto = sf.sengines.options[sf.sengines.selectedIndex].value + escape(sf.searchterms.value);
window.location.href = submitto;
return false;
}
</script>

<form name="searchform" onSubmit="return dosearch();">
<input type="text" name="searchterms">
<select name="sengines">
<option value="http://www.google.com/search?q=" selected>Dealers</option>
<option value="http://www.altavista.com/web/results?q=">Products</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
```